# Outlook 2013 issues with office 365 and onsite Exchange server

Tags: email, outlook, office365, exchange-server-2007

Our Global company is in the process of rolling out office 365 for the whole group. currently i am the only user in my location to start using office 365. I can create a new outlook 2013 profile for the office 365 account and it works well. Problem i'm having is after launching the new Office 365 profile outlook keeps prompting me for my local windows username and password. this only happens when i'm connecting to my local network. Our local exchange server is still in production and cant be removed at this stage as all my other 400+ users use it.

If i connect to my office 365 profile in outlook from another network this does not happen.

I created a new profile for outlook 2013 and this still occurs. 
If i enter my credentials in outlook 2013 it downloads my local OAB instead of using the new Office 365 address book. 
Current setup: Local Exchange 2007 server.
Office 2013 on windows 7 64bit

Comment: Did you try repairing/reinstalling Office?

Comment: Yes I have. Uninstalled and reinstalled office

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft employee here - sorry to hear about the difficulties you're having!

Can you answer these questions for me:

```
1. What specific Outlook 2013 version are you using? e.g. 15.0.4631.1000  
2. Does the problem still occur if you set the ExcludeScpLookup Autodiscover reg value? Steps to do so can be found below:  
    a. Start regedit  
    b. Select reg key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover  
    c. Create a new DWORD value in this AutoDiscover reg key named "ExcludeScpLookup" (no quotes) with value 1
    d. Restart Outlook and boot into your O365 profile
```

Note that #2 is not a permanent solution, just a troubleshooting step to determine where the issue might be occurring. Please delete that reg value after confirming whether or not the issue still occurs with it set.

Thanks!